# How do I know which equal number contains me?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array like this:

```
let A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and I want Which parameter is equal === 4

```
array.includes(4) //true
```

Top code just show me true but i want show me array[3] is 4

Comment: Use `arr.indexOf(4)` to get the index of `4`.

Comment: Use `.findIndex` method of array to get the index  e.g. A.findIndex(num => num == 4);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.indexOf()` instead of `.includes()`

```
let A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
let index = A.indexOf(4)
```

**Output :** index = 3